# pandas pd.date_range: create 2 hours interval during 24 hours excluding weekends and hoildays

Tags: python, pandas

pandas pd.date_range: Does anyone knows how to create 2 hours interval (during 24 hours) excluding weekends and hoildays.

I tried this:
f = CustomBusinessHour(2, start = '00:00', end = '22:00', calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

res = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-10', freq=f)

But this goes only till 20:00

Thanks a lot!

Comment: and if I do the end like that: 
f = CustomBusinessHour(2, start = '00:00', end = '23:59', calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
Then the next day starts at 00:01 and not at 00:00, e.g,  '2021-01-05 00:01:00'